# Visual Studio: The system cannot find the path specified

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, model, ado.net-entity-data-model

I am developing a website in ASP.NET MVC in Visual Studio. I'm trying to add a Database connection, but it gives me the error "The system cannot find the path specified".

Here's what I am doing:

- Right Click on Models Folder
- New Item > ADO.NET Entity Data Model
- EF Designer from Database
- New Connection (SQL Database connection test succeeds)
- Choose the tables I want to include
- Press Finish
- Error Appears

The Output Window says the following:

```
Generated model file: Model1.edmx.
Loading metadata from the database took 00:00:01.3576925.
Generating the model took 00:00:01.3134936.
```

However, the Models Folder is empty and no connection strings are made. I have been trying for about an hour and nothing, deleted the .vs, bin, and obj folders, rebuilt the solution but nothing works. I appreciate any help you can provide.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

After much troubleshooting, I managed to fix the issue, details below:

- Delete Models folder (backup any files inside)
- Create a new empty Models folder
- Add the new Model

Hope this helps anyone with this issue.

Comment: Thanks. Had the exact same issue

Comment: Glad I could help!